# How to create image and labels using location data stored in NSArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i have to create an 2images and 3 labels by using code (cgrectmake)and i am having X location, y location, width and height all are stored in arrays(which i have retrieved from the web services)how can i create the image and labels can any one help me

Comment: Satya, you'll have to be more clear. Can you post the `NSArray` you're talking about? What string are you looking to get out of it?

Comment: What are lbl, lbl1, lbl2? (are they NSString's, or?)

Comment: Downvoting due to limited English skills seems harsh, don't you think?

Comment: @Matthew, was thinking the same thing. Definitely a language barrier

Comment: @satya Please edit your question to add an example of what you want as the result. If you want a string at the end, please write an example of that string. If you want an array at the end, please write an example of what the original string contains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be this is usefull to you.

```
NSString *str;

str = [arrayName objectAtIndex:i(Index NO)];
```

OK by this easily you can access object from the array. any type of object u can fetch this way only reception object type are change in left side.

Best of Luck.

Answer (score 2):

You can join the elements of an array together with the NSString **componentsJoinedByString** class method:

```
NSString myString = [myNSArray componentsJoinedByString:@"x"];
```

where **x** is the characters you'd like to appear between each array element.

---

**Edited to add**

So in your newly-added code if these are the label values:

**`lbl = @"zero"`**
**`lbl1 = @"one"`**
**`lbl2 = @"two"`**

and you want to join them together with a space character then if you did this:

```
NSString *temp = [labelArray componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
NSLog(@"temp = %@", temp);
```

then this is what would be logged:

**`zero one two`**

---

**Edited to further add**

If you are instead trying to join the label values together to make xml elements then you might do something like this:

```
NSString *joinedElements = [labelArray componentsJoinedByString:@"</label><label>"];
NSString *temp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<label>%@</label>", joinedElements];
NSLog(@"temp = %@", temp);
```

then this is what would be logged:

**`<label>zero</label><label>one</label><label>two</label>`**

Answer (score 0):

Most objects have a -description method which returns a string representation of the object:

```
- (NSString *)description;
```

For example:

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"The", @"quick", @"brown", @"fox", nil];
NSLog(@"%@", array); // prints the contents of the array out to the console.
NSString *arrayDescription = [array description]; // a string
```

It would help to know what you want to do with the string (how will you use the string). Also, what kind of objects do you have in the array?

In that case, Matthew's answer is one possibility. Another might be to use an NSMutableString and append the individual items, if you need control over how the string is created:

```
NSMutableString *string = [NSMutableString string];
if ([array count] >= 3) {
    [string appendString:[array objectAtIndex:0]];
    [string appendFormat:@"blah some filler text %@", [array objectAtIndex:1]];
    [string appendString:[array objectAtIndex:2]];
}
```

Comment: i am working on parsing found characters in this i had an array and i want to covert it in to nsstring shown above...